# App crashes when back after a period of time(Press home)

Tags: android, crash, nullpointerexception

If the app runs visible,everything gets fine.But if I press home to let the app in the background and do some other things, it would get a crash like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.qdn.bus/com.qdn.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2001)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2028)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1179)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9999)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9975)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9951)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at com.qdn.activity.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4489)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9999)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9975)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2408)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9951)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at com.qdn.activity.MainActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnStart(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4489)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2028)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1179)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it is because the Delvik Vm has recycle some of the memory.But is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Nothing to do with `Dalvik Vm recycling some memory`.  Please read about, understand and learn the Activity Life Cycle.  For now, please show the onStart() method of MainActivity.

Comment: There's a `NullPointerException`. The problem should be there

Comment: @Simon The onStart method only called {super.onStart();}.If it is only because Activity Life Cycle,why it is fine for the most time when it run in background(also called onstop and onstart),only for some time.Thank you very much

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine I think so.However,I do not know which variable will be null atfer some time inthe background.And as above, the onstart method only called super.onStart()

Comment: What views are inside the ViewPager? anything custom? or do you use Fragments (if so, you have fragments in a viewpager which itself is inside a fragment - are you using the child fragment manager?)

Comment: @FunkTheMonk The viewpager is in my fragment of my MainActivity.There are only two expandable listviews in viewpager